# Retrieve data from firebase to tableview ( EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error )

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve data from firebase to tableview. I have three label in a single cell as comment title , comment and date.  Every single label has a tag (1,2,3) in the prototype cell and I have the following code

[image]

```
struct commentStruct {
let title : String!
let comment : String!
let date : String!
 }


class ListComments: UITableViewController {

var comments = [commentStruct]()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")


    let root = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    root.child("Comments").queryOrderedByKey().observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: {
        snapshot in

        let t = snapshot.value!["title"] as! String
        let c = snapshot.value!["comment"] as! String
        let d = snapshot.value!["date"] as! String!

        self.comments.insert(commentStruct(title:t , comment:c , date:d), atIndex: 0)
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    })


}
```

And my cellForRowAtIndexPath method is

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")




    let label1 = cell!.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
    label1.text = comments[indexPath.row].title


    let label2 = cell!.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
    label2.text = comments[indexPath.row].comment

    let label3 = cell!.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel
    label3.text = comments[indexPath.row].date

    return cell!

     }


  }
```

I got the error EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code = EXC_i386_INVOP)

Comment: Set the exception breakpoint to get more detailed information about the crash (I guess the reason is the very popular *Unexpected found nil...*). The table seems to be designed in Interface Builder, why do you register the cell explicitly? By the way: Use the more convenient `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath` to get a guaranteed valid non-optional cell. And why don't you use a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell` to be able to provide `IBOutlet`s for the additional labels?

Comment: @vadian Thank you so much for suggestions. I'm very new at Swift and IOS Programming. I will search and try your suggestions